# How to tell if workstation is currently connected to a domain controller with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, networking, active-directory, network-programming

I wrote a C++ program that is designed to run on a workstation connected to the domain controller in the Active Directory set-up. It works great, except the following situation.

Say, a user installs it on a laptop that is connect to the DC, but then moves that laptop away from the Active Directory environment (say, goes home with it where DC is not accessible.)

Is there any way to detect this from my software?

Comment: NetGetJoinInformation ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa370423(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @AlexK. NetGetJoinInformation will return the same value NetSetupDomainName even when domain is not accessible -- just checked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try to bind to or search for a known object in the AD. If binding succeeds we should be in the domain. Assuming the user is logged in with an off-line AD profile, you could try to bind to the current user:

```
IADs *pObject;
HRESULT hr;

CoInitialize(NULL);
hr = ADsGetObject(L"LDAP://CN=user,DC=domain,DC=com", IID_IADs, (void**) &pObject);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // AD is available
    pObject->Release()
}
else
{
    // AD is NOT available
}
CoUninitialize();
```

Have a look at [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation in MSDN, most of it works only when you have access to AD.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I thought about doing the same too, but the situation here is how would I know that the binding failed because the domain is not accessible, or because of some other legitimate error?

Comment: @user843732 It needs a bit of digging into your exact requirements and ultimately you might want to go through [ADSI error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and decide which ones are legitimate. Two codes I'd look for are `LDAP_CONNECT_ERROR` and `LDAP_UNAVAILABLE`.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be the way to handle it.